# uwsgi: strange error message: unknown config directive: inifile

Tags: linux, uwsgi

I have a uwsgi.ini file. It works perfectly, but if I add `strict=true` it fails with the message

```
[strict-mode] unknown config directive: inifile
```

however the word `inifile` doesn't even exist in my inifile.

In order to reproduce the error I went so far, that I created a uwsgi.ini file with only two lines.

```
[uwsgi]
strict=true
```

If I run `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`
I get above mentioned error

If I set strict to false I get of course errors about missing parameters.

Even if I use a yaml file with following contents:

```
uwsgi:
    strict: true
```

and I call with `uwsgi -y uwsgi.yaml`

I get:

```
[uWSGI] getting YAML configuration from uwsgi.yaml
[strict-mode] unknown config directive: inifile
```

So I think uwsgi wants to tell me something different, but I don't know what.

I like to keep the [strict flag](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog-1.9.15.html?highlight=strict#strict-mode) to be protected against typos or options that became obsolete or just exist in newer versions. It is difficult to diagnose if I don't get help finding the offending line.

I tested with uwsgi 2.0.18 and 2.0.21

Comment: please take a look at [ask] because for the moment the question is off topic due it does not fulfill the minimum requirements for serverfault.com

Comment: I read "How to Ask" and am not sure what exactly you are missing. 
Do you think that this question is more appropriate for Superuser? If so I can delete it and post it there.

If it's something else, then please tell me.

- serverfault has a tag uwsgi. As my problem is a uwsgi problem I tagged it with it.
- The title describes the problem
- my question contains all necessary information to reproduce the issue and shows what I tried already.
- I specified the uwsgi versions I tested with.

Please clarify

Comment: I added the 'linux' tag and fixed a few minor typos

Comment: as I added the linux tag I also prefixed the question with uwsgi. so that even users who look at the question due to the linux tag know immediately that the issue is a uwsgi issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not in your file, it could still be from one of the [other source](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html) of configuration.

You may not have that option in the specified file. But uwsgi, by default, parses environment minus the `UWSGI_` prefix, should you have anything starting with that there. Confirm it using:

```bash
env | grep -i uwsgi
```

Comment: Your answer is spot on.

I completely missed this second source for uwsgi directives.

I do have indeed an environment variable `UWSGI_INIFILE` which indicates where I can locate the configuration file of uwsgi.

I need this for another tool and under some circumstances the parent process starting uwsgi can see this environment variable.

I guess I have to rename it.